# Elastic Search query string request

Tags: android, elasticsearch

I am using elastic search in my Android application. I am passing filters in query string like below:

```
URL/IndexName/TypeName/_search?sort=registry_date:desc&from=0&size=10&q=firstname:رشید
```

That works fine. But i want to apply a **prefix filter** on firstname field for achieving below thing through query string:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "prefix": {
            "firstname.keyword": "رشید"
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [],
      "should": []
    }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10,
  "sort": [
    {
      "registry_date": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "aggs": {}
}
```

Any help?

Comment: By prefix filter do you mean, for example, all names starting with "Fre". Would match "Fred" and "Freddy"?

Comment: @RishiDiwan yes . And I am referring to the prefix word in structured query in my question.

Comment: What is your ES version?
If sufficiently updated https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-prefix-query.html

Comment: @RishiDiwan I can't append that in query string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot find now where I found this but for me (on Elasticsearch version 5.4) works something like this:

```
URL/IndexName/TypeName/_search?source=PLACE_JSON_HERE
```

where `PLACE_JSON_HERE` could be entire JSON which you are passing as a POST body.

So for example:

```
URL/IndexName/TypeName/_search?source={"query":{"match_all":{}}}
```

will return all the documents.

In your situation you can even replace the `PLACE_JSON_HERE` with:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "prefix": {
            "firstname.keyword": "رشید"
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [],
      "should": []
    }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10,
  "sort": [
    {
      "registry_date": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "aggs": {}
}
```

But as I said I cannot find this in ES documentation now so I do not know if it works on all versions.

---

### UPDATE

Tested on 6.2.2 version:

```
http://localhost:9200/_doc/_search?source={"query":{"match_all":{}}}&source_content_type=application/json
```

Works as expected. `source_content_type` is required with `source` since ES 6.

Comment: @Naila please take a look at my update. It works for me on the newest ES (6.2.2) version.